# Weight painting a dot and not a gradient

Tags: weight-painting

I'm following a tutorial where the person quickly goes over everything so you have to have knowledge of the program. I am starting on beginners tutorials but had a look at [How to Make Towels - Blender Tutorial](https://youtu.be/PEpsN1-W-Qw?t=189)   At 03:14 he adds in a weight in the form of a dot.  When I tried to do this mine came out as a gradient (imagine using a gradient where the point is in the middle).

How do I change this to show as a dot?

Comment: check to have enough subdivisions, too... he had over 5000 vertices when painting

Answer (score 4):

His is also a radial gradient, but smaller.
Make sure you are using a Draw brush in the Tool panel <kbd>T</kbd>.
You can make the brush smaler with <kbd>F</kbd> so each stroke will be more like a dot. You can also change the size of the "gradient" around it by choosing a different brush curve:

[image]